# How to remove hyphen from TextUtils.split(line, "-")?

Tags: android, database

I found a dictionary sample in GitHub that I am currently experimenting with. The sample database used hyphen between the searched word and the word's meaning. So something like this.

abbey - n. a monastery ruled by an abbot

I looked into the dictionary database java file and found the following code:

String[] strings = TextUtils.split(line, "-");

I have my own database that translates Korean words to English. However I didn't use hyphen while creating it. So is there a way to not use hyphen or any other symbols but simply spaces? Also this is part of an android app.

Edit- An example of my own dictionary would be something like

abbey  a monastery ruled by an abbot

Edit- 
The problem here is that the old code only differentiates and recognizes the words and the meaning only if they are separated by hyphen. How do I make this so it works with spaces alone.

Comment: What you want?remove or split.both are different things

Comment: Is your database containing those values in one column ? What do you want ? To keep splitting the value and get an `String[]` with your pattern ?

Comment: I want to change this remove this code and add a new one which the app understands to split the word and meaning from spaces alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove a character in a String use [String.replace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29)

`String newString = line.replace("-","");`

To replace with a space simply use

`String newString = line.replace("-"," ");`

Answer (score 0):

String mystring = mystring 1.replace("_"," "); if you want space give space.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you want to split your `String` to get the output like

```
abbey - n. a monastery ruled by an abbot
[abbey][n. a monastery ruled by an abbot]
```

You can use [`String.split(String, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int)) to force the number of split.

> The limit parameter controls the number of times the pattern is applied and therefore affects the length of the resulting array. If the limit n is greater than zero then the pattern will be applied at most n - 1 times

Let's use it like :

```
String[] array = s.split(" ", 2);
```

This will split your `String` on the regex `" "` but will limit the size of the output to 2 cells. So it will only split once, put the left part on the first cell and the right part on the second cell.

Without this limit argument, the method would keep split the right part again using a bigger array.

Note: this will be a problem if your word is a sentence in the left part.